plm and time effects
To estimate a panel data using the within model,we use the plm package
For example if I have two variables, y, x we have
m1<-  plm(y~ x,  data = df,   index = c("Country", "year"), model="within")

In this link https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/plm/vignettes/A_plmPackage.html
it reads that

The default behavior of plm is to introduce individual effects. Using the effect argument, one may also introduce:
time effects (effect = "time"),
individual and time effects (effect = "twoways").

My question is the following. If
 m1<-  plm(y~ x,  data = df,   index = c("Country", "year"), effect = "time", model="within")

does this mean that the above regression contains only time fixed effects but not country fixed effects?
